# Search both site meta and MSO from the Search bar

Tags: feature-request, search, meta, per-site-meta

When I'm trying to figure out how something works on an SE site, I need to look at both my site meta and at MSO. Wouldn't it make more sense if the search bar on a site meta searched both that meta and the global meta?

Comment: I can't understand *how something works*.

Comment: @hims056 I'm sorry? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I mean: What do you mean by *I'm trying to figure out how something works on an SE site*.

Comment: For example, if I want to know etiquette rules for a situation. Or how I should be flagging. Or if I want to see if other people have some bug. Or if I want to know how people handle things. I'm pretty new to SE, so I'm trying to learn what the community tends to approve and disapprove of.

Comment: Etiquette is highly different from site to site: What SO closes as NARQ/NC and highly downvotes, TeX.SX keep at 0 or -1 and comment. The way how you should flag partly depends on what moderators of the site prefer, especially in smaller sites they can have a different approach. And more importantly, it would confuse people, jumping from one site to a completely different one. If you have a question, you can always ask on "your meta", and the only thing that can happen is that you are pointed to a thread on MSO.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a workaround would be to google something like:

```
site:meta.stackoverflow.com OR site:meta.something.stackexchange.com [your search terms]
```